# Uploading image over 2M in Laravel has no path

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

When I upload an image that is over 2MB to my Laravel application, it comes in as `application/octet-stream` mime type instead of `image/jpeg`, and it also has no temp path. My controller looks like this:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $file = $request->file('entry_photo');
        ...
    }
}
```

If I run `dd($file);`, it shows that the path is just my public directory and the mime is `application/octet-stream`. This only happens on images over 2M. My php_ini has `upload_max_filesize` set to 10M, and post_max_size to 8M. I'm sure this is a server thing, but can't seem to figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest outputting `phpinfo()` on a temporary page to figure out whether the changes you have made to you php.ini have taken effect. I've fallen into the trap of not restarting fpm before and therfore the changes not applying.

Secondly, if you are using nginx make sure you have the following in your nginx config

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

More info on nginx settings for file uploads can be found here:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/

Comment: Apparently Nginx hadn't restarted after I had made the changes, even though it said it had. It kept showing the old values. I had to restart the server and then it worked.